# Unable to plot the boxplots using subplots

Tags: python, boxplot

```
fig,axes = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(8,7))

sns.boxplot(payments['payment_installments'],axes[0,0])
sns.boxplot(payments['payment_value'],axes[0,1])
```

The error says: IndexError: too many indices for array

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you gave too many indices for the array axes. It should be :

```
sns.boxplot(x=payments['payment_installments'],ax=axes[0]))
sns.boxplot(x=payments['payment_value'],ax=axes[1])
```

because axes is one dimensional :

```
array([<AxesSubplot:>, <AxesSubplot:>], dtype=object)
```

Comment: It still didn't work, I have tried this before but I get an error saying:

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'AxesSubplot'

Comment: What could be nrows and ncols value in subplots()?

Comment: @AishwaryaWuntkal : Sorry, I edited my answer. The parameters names were missing in my first answer.

Comment: @AishwaryaWuntkal : The nrows and ncols are the number of rows and columns as int. You defined it in the good way.